# Gradle script to copy maven artifact from local folder to another folder

Tags: gradle

In my project i want to copy certain artifact (war file) from maven repo to local folder in order to deploy. I tried using configurations object but i couldn't give specific groupid, artifact id, and version in that way

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral() // or some other repo
}

configurations {
    deploy
}

dependencies {
    deploy "someGroup:someArtifact:someVersion"
}

task copyDeploy(type: Copy) {
    from configurations.deploy
    into "deploy"
}
```

You can find all of this and more in the [Gradle User Guide](http://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/userguide_single.html) (e.g. under "Working with dependencies") and the many samples in the full Gradle distribution.

Comment: Is there a way to add some "deploy" dependency by default to a project (considering I am using the above in a Gradle plugin)?